# Is Melech ever a verb?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, prayer-book, translation, rosh-hashanah-new-year

In the Artscroll machzor (ashkenaz), in the Chazarat Hashatz for shacharit of Rosh Hashana, the piyut with the refrain "Hashem Melech, Hashem malach, Hashem yimloch le'olam va'ed" has a strange translation.

The second and third uses of the m-l-ch root are cited as verbs (reigned and will reign) but the first Melech, is translated as reigns. However, the word "Melech" as far as I can find, is always used as a noun ("king") and the present tense verb would be "molech" (as used in the first pasuk of megillat Esther).

In fact, the Artscroll Tanach has, as the translation of the phrase in the source pasuk (Tehillim 10:16) "Hashem is king" (as it does when citing that pasuk in Mashechet Rosh Hashana).

It could be said that there is no effective difference between "reigns" and "is king" (though I could make a contrary argument -- often the one who reigns is not king, and a king does not always actively reign) and that the Artscroll is trying to establish parallelism but I'm just curious: Is there any textual precedent to its use as a verb, or, lacking that, is there something deeper in the word "melech" that properly allows it to be translated as "reigns"?

[strangely, one of the machzorim available through [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz%2C_The_Morning_Prayers%2C_First_Day_of_Rosh_Hashana%2C_Reader's_Repetition.70?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) was all three as nouns (is king, was king, will be king)]

Comment: contextually, it sounds like the phrase is meant to be present, past, and future of the same concept. perhaps the author is limiting himself though to excerpts from scripture and/or avoiding a name of a foreign god.

Comment: FWIW, See 3rd paragraph in http://www.abarim-publications.com/Meaning/Melech.html#.XZUgIE2Wyic. It suggests an Aramaic cognate which seems to suggest its usage as a verb.

Comment: Of course, "הוּא אֲחַשְׁוֵרוֹשׁ הַמֹּלֵךְ מֵהֹדּוּ וְעַד־כּוּשׁ". In Hebrew there are two forms of פעל, like לגדול - הוא גדל או הוא גודל. Same can be applied to למלוך - הוא מלך או הוא מולך.

Comment: @AlBerko How are you vowelizing הוא גדל?

Comment: @rosends If you can still see my answer, see the paragraph beginning, "But it could also simply be understood as a noun, etc", in regard to you question about it being used as a noun. Hope you understand the idea.

Comment: Why and how was my answer deleted by someone? I’m in the middle of adding additional sources!

Comment: @IsaacMoses One of the 3 moderators for MY deleted my answer to this question. I would like to know why, specifically, it was deleted? It answers the question posed directly, is not offensive in any way and is sourced with direct quotes and text links with citations. There are zero comments suggesting any changes. What’s the problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA I ask you the same question that I posed to IsaacMoses directly above?

Comment: Why is my answer still deleted by the moderator msh210? It does not appear at all in the phone app. All 3 of you have been reported to SE again for abuse of moderator privileges. Please stop the abusive behavior and baseless hatred.

Comment: @Yaacov I didn't see your comment till now because I wasn't pinged since I haven't commented on this post. The answer was deleted by three users with 20k rep which is [an ordinary privilege at that level](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). I haven't reviewed it (it is rather lengthy) to see if it falls in one of the two categories for ordinary user deletion, namely "The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement" and 
"The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether."

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for replying. It seems that when a moderator (msh210 in this case) deletes, it isn’t the same as others. My answer is completely gone except via a browser. And that doesn’t even address why this particular answer is being targeted. It’s a completely valid and sourced answer dealing with the specific questions posed by the OP in their question.

Comment: @Yaacov as with all deleted answers, no matter who deleted them, the answer will only be visible by the poster and users with 10k rep, and it will not be visible to anyone using the app. I haven't reviewed your answer in detail but 3 users with 20k rep all voting to delete something negatively voted doesn't usually lend itself to very drastic mistakes. Though anything is possible.

Comment: @DoubleAA If what you report is accurate, then it emphasizes even more that moderators need to tread lightly in the moderation process. It can destroy legitimate hard work of other people. I would like my answer restored so it’s visible to the general public.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I can't answer below but just to clarify -- I don't provide any examples of melech as verb. I show that one machzor in one situation translates it as a verb but there is no precedent for this as far as I can tell, so I'm asking for other examples.

Comment: @DoubleAA No comments and no suggestions from those 3 individuals. DonielF commented. I responded & his last comment was that he was intending to remove his down vote. Like I explained to him, I answered the main question in the title first (same procedure recommended in Avot). I then began editing in the long part dealing with the bigger subject. It’s all sourced, quoted & linked...and in progress! There is no justification for deleting this.

Comment: @rosends I read your entire question carefully. I know you cited the English translation from Sefaria for the Ashkenazi Machzor. FWIW, the English translation of the Chabad Machzor (translation by a noted linguist, Rabbi Nisan Mangel) also translates “is King...was King...will be King”. It’s a good question, but the main part is your closing question about deeper meaning in connection with the letter root and associated vowels. And that is the body of my answer. I hope you can read it.

Comment: @YaacovDeane In your answer, could you please 1) Delete the beginning part, which addresses "*moleich*" rather than "*melech*". 2) Make it clear, preferably through editing to focus and clarify rather than adding more text, how you're proposing that the word "*melech*" can be properly translated as "reigns" (the question at hand)? There's a great deal in the answer that doesn't directly address this point, and it's hard to find a clear resolution of this point, in particular. The more additional background you include, the more it's helpful to be careful to highlight the core response.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I see your comments. I probably won’t be able to get to this until I’m in front of a browser. But just to note, the opening part of my answer is relevant to the OP’s current question and confirms his suspicion about proper present tense for the Kal verb root מלך as used in Tanach. It’s relevant for pointing out that contextually in relation to the same verb root in the balance of the posuk, it’s abnormal. That indicates there is something special to learn from it.

Comment: @YaacovDeane If it's helpful information to support your answer, please edit to make it clear and put it clearly in a supporting role. The form it's in now - "Is Melech ever a verb? Yes, Moleich is a verb." appears to be a misguided attempt to answer the first question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Not a problem. The OP is writing in English, so in context of his discussion about verbs in Hebrew, my understanding was that he was referencing the verb root and then pointing out various translations and nekudot in Hebrew sources. But if you want me to point out that this is what he appears to be saying, I’ll, bli neder, touch on it.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Please don't interpret any of my suggestions as a request to *increase* the amount of text. What I'm trying to prompt you to do is focus on answering the question at hand, which is very explicitly about the word *melech*, vowelized exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find a direct verb usage of *melech*. However, it's possible that the term means "takes advice / council". See [Nechemia 5:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14260&st=&pgnum=196).

Comment: Nice, but this seems to be an Aramaic root, like we find in other contexts נמלך means something like to have change of intent

Comment: @DoubleAA Most likely, yes. However, as we know, numerous Hebrew words (Hava, for example) are originally Aramaic.

Comment: @DoubleAA Radak says that both the Hebrew and the Aramaic can have a meaning of advising. See Shorashim l’Radak, pg 195 under the nifal binyan for מלך.